# Can anyone identify what kind of block these hinged blocks are?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

They all link together. I added a normal Lego brick to compare size.

I have had no luck with Google.

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Those are quite interesting aren't they? Sadly I've no idea what they are, but it's possible someone else might...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Woah! I haven't thought of these in years... Flashback to [FLEXIBLOCKS](http://www.flexiblocks.com)!!!

[image: Flexiblocks Jumbo Set]

[image: Flexiblocks Helicopter]